# Moment JS and BST

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Going out of mind with this. So I have the following:

```
 var now = moment().local();
 var timestamp = now.unix();
```

But the timestamp is always one hour behind and I cant figure out why. If I log now in the console I get what I expect:

```
Tue Jun 09 2020 19:19:32 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
```

But when I log timestamp to the console I get

```
1591726782
```

Which equates to:

```
Tue, 09 Jun 2020 18:19:32 GMT
```

Driving me completely potty. Probably a really simple solution but I have trawled the web and checked MomentJS documentation and cant see where I am going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Those are the same time, just in different timezones. They both represent the same underlying GMT time.

Comment: What timezone are you in?

Comment: What's not to get? You go from GMT + 1 hour to GMT and it's one hour less. That's the whole point of the +0100...

Comment: Don't say "what's not to get", it's a little rude. Clearly this user is missing something that is obvious to you, don't make them feel bad about it.

Comment: Im in GMT - Just trying to work out why the UNIX timestamp is an hour behind the local time and how to get it to be the correct time as moment.local() shows.

Comment: moment seems to think you're not in GMT

Comment: Even if I set this  var tick = moment().tz("Europe/London"); it is still the same.